# How to redirect to a specific route declared as Route::controllers

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I want to redirect to the login page from another controller. I'm used to using `Redirect::route`, but the routes are defined as `Route::controllers`.

The routes that come with laravel's installation:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Is there a way I could declare some of the routes as named route and then use it in `Redirect::route`?

Comment: you can name your route with use of 'as' Route::get('/bag/create_bag/', ['as' => 'bag_err', 'uses' => 'bagController@create_bag']);

Comment: But that's when I'm declaring a single route. So I have to remove `Route::controllers` and declare all of the routes and name them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name your routes inside the controller route definition:

> If you would like to name some of the routes on the controller, you
>   may pass an array of names as the third argument to the controller
>   method:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController', [
    'getShow' => 'user.show',
]);
```

Then you should be able to get the url like this:

```
$url = route('user.show');
```

Or you can get the url without assigning a name by using both controller and action:

```
$url = action('UserController@getShow');
```

Finally there's always a "direct" url:

```
$url = url('user/show');
```

Info from [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers)

About naming directly inside `controllers` method. That's from laravel core:

```
public function controllers(array $controllers)
{
    foreach ($controllers as $uri => $controller)
    {
        $this->controller($uri, $controller);
    }
}
```

As you can see names are not accepted or passed to controller method so you probably can't do that. If you wanna assign route names you'll have to split `Route:controllers` into separate `Route::controller` and add names array.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. Thanks again for your answer. But what about >Route::controller**s** definition? Or I should split them into two separate `Route::controller`?

Comment: I guess if you wanna name the routes slitting will definitely work.

Comment: I was just wondering if there's another way to name some of the routes which is applicable to `Route::controllers` just like `Route::controller` :)